# C# How to seperate string character by character

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have parsed a response from an Api into date string, and its data. The date string shows as:

```
"201710010900000"
```

What i am trying to to do is convert this into a format that can be read by `date` `mm/dd/yyyy` to do this

i must grab the first 4 letters as year, the next 2 as month, the next 2 as day. ideally call these into separate strings date,month,day. that way it can be converted into one string.

```
string reDate = (month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

Is there a way to call each character of the string individually, Or what would be the best  way to do this?

Comment: A string is an array of characters. Just iterate over it. You don't need to do that if you want to parse this as a date though, as you should. Just use `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: `Parse` it into `DateTime` and `Format` it to the desired output format?

Comment: each string will be different as i am calling from a list. Current format is yyyymmddttttttt.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get where your problem is. You know the input format and output format. What is stopping you?

Comment: thank you i will look into the documention on how to use DateTime.ParseExact.

Comment: You should mark the answer that helped you as helpful, so the question gets answered.

Answer (score 8):

A string is an array of characters. Just iterate over it or use an indexer, eg:

```
var someChar="201710010900000"[0];
```

You don't need to do that if you want to parse this as a date though, as you should. Just use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx), eg:

```
var input="201710010900000";
var format="yyyyMMddHHmmssf";
var date=DateTime.ParseExact(input,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Other overloads allow you to specify multiple formats, eg [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx).

ParseExact will throw an exception if the conversion fails. If you expect this to be a common occurence, you can use [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
var styles=DateTimeStyles.None;
var culture=CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input,format,culture,styles,out var date))
{
    //Do something with the date
}
```

Once you have the DateTime value you can use [the standard string formatting mechanisms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) to generate a string with the format you want, in the culture you want.

If you want a US-style short date, you can write any of the following :

```
var targetCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
var text1=date.ToString("d",targetCulture);
var text2=String.Format(targetCulture,"This is my date: {0:d}",result);
```

Answer (score 6):

`DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` were made for this purpose:

```
DateTime dt;
bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact("201710010900000", "yyyyMMddHHmmssf", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

To separate the day, month etc you just need to use the available properties:

```
int year = dt.Year;
int month = dt.Month;
int day = dt.Day;
int hour = dt.Hour;
```

If you want the return string with this format: `month+"/"+ day+"/"+year` use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
string returnString = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `MM` is month, `mm` is minute, with leading zeroes for both.

Comment: I remember getting roasted for suggesting `/` a few years back. Some cultures *don't* use `/` as the date separator, eg Russian. `InvariantCulture` just "happens" to use the US styles - simply using the `d` format would produce `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 3):

`ParseExact` into `DateTime` and then represent it as a `String`:

```
  string source = "201710010900000";

  string result = DateTime
    .ParseExact(source, "yyyyMMddHHmmssf", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");
```

Comment: `'/'` :D. I know at least one culture that uses `.` instead of `/`. Annoying. Breaks quite a few popular CSV parsers, let me tell you!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, if there only were a Standard for that ...

Comment: @Fildor, yes, it's called "Let the customer deal with it"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos :D Is that an ISO? haha

Comment: I've put `'/'` insisting on `/` regardless the culture since the question has `string reDate = (month+"/"+ day+"/"+year);` line

Comment: @Fildor If I started mentioning payment gateways, someone could think I was trolling. It's not *their* payment gateway, promise. It's the one that's suffixed with `ndex`

Comment: @DragandDrop never had to work with bank and payment gateway reports I presume? Besides, changing the extension of a text file to a non-text format isn't going to help with *anything*. Especially when said gateway stores email headers and PGP footers in said file

Answer (score 1):

If your plan is to 'iterate' over the response you can try something like:

```
var input = "201710010900000";
var year = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(0, 4));
var month = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(4, 2));
var day = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(6, 2));
var hour = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(8, 2));
var minutes = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(10, 2));
var seconds = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(12, 2));

var date = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

I hope it helps,

Another aproach is to create a new date specifying the imput format as somebody else answered here (and to be fair a very good aproach).

Juan

Comment: you missed the single `0` at the end

Comment: That's not iterating. These are expensive substring operations. If the OP really wanted to iterate in order to *avoid* generating substrings this is exactly what *shouldn't* be done

Comment: That's 100% true